# NHS eligibility?

Tags: united-kingdom, australia, nhs

First post here. Have a somewhat tricky situation and would appreciate any advice.

I was born in the UK in 1997, and moved to Australia with my family in 2004. Long story short, I am going on exchange through my Australian university back to the UK (I know, might seem silly, but I want to spend time with my grandmother and sister, etc.), and I am unclear on whether I am still eligible to receive free NHS healthcare.

I still hold a UK passport, have returned there for periods of a month or two almost every year since leaving, and will be there for six months. I will have a stable address for the six month period and will be studying full-time.

I am unclear on whether I will fit the regulations for being 'ordinarily resident', as it describes the term as meaning 'An individual who is living lawfully in the United Kingdom voluntarily
and for settled purposes as part of the regular order of their life for
the time being, whether of long or short duration, with an identifiable
purpose for their residence here which has a sufficient degree of
continuity to be properly described as settled.'

Part of the reason I ask is that I have some blood tests I need to get done, but not enough time to get them done in Australia now before I leave. If nobody knows, does anyone at least know who I should contact to find out?

Comment: Do you have an Australian passport as well? IF you're somehow not eligible for NHS, which I'd be surprised by, you certainly could be covered by the [reciprocal healthcare agreement between the UK and Australia](https://www.humanservices.gov.au/customer/enablers/rhca-visiting-united-kingdom)

Comment: Also, when will you be returning? Looks like [some of the cost rules might change from October](http://www.nhs.uk/NHSEngland/AboutNHSservices/uk-visitors/visiting-england/Pages/visitors-from-outside-the-eea.aspx)

Comment: Hi! I do indeed have an Australian passport as well, I'll definitely look into that! And I'll be returning in February, so those changes could also impact me. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @MarkMayo +1 very much an answer, with both links.